# specify ouput file name flash builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, rename

This should be easy, but I can't find it.  I want my .html and .swf files to be named something differently than the project name.  Project name is foo, I want the outputs to be bar.html and bar.swf. Thanks.

Comment: Since you mention "Project" I assume you're using an IDE?  Perhaps you should tell us which one.  ( Flash Builder? ).  I would have guessed Flash Builder, but in Flash Builder the name of the generated SWF is the name of the main application file; not the name of the project.

Comment: Ahh, ok.  Flash Builder 4.  The main application is foo.as. Can I name the output bar.swf?

Comment: You can rename it after the fact; but I don't think you can change the name during compile time.  You'll have to check the command line compiler arguments.  If you add a bar.html in your html-template directory I believe it will copy to your bin-debug or bin-release.  If you add a file named bar.template.html I think it'll create a bar.html file in your bin-debug / bin-release folders.

Answer (score 1):

Flextras was on the right track.  You can't change the output filename (even using the "-output" compiler param) if you're compiling in Flash Builder.  Not sure why.

The solution that has worked for me has been to use a bit of indirection:

1. use mxmlc to compile to ApplicationClass.swf
2. command line copy ApplicationClass.swf to YourCustomSwf.swf
3. command line run YourCustomSwf.swf

You can do this with either a simple (platform-dependent) build script, or with Flex Ant Tasks.  I highly recommend the latter; it's [easy to setup](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ant_pt1.html), integrates well with Flash Builder, and (as a mostly platform-independent solution) will work in a multi-team multi-OS environment.  Here are the above steps as ant tasks that will perform the magic for you:

```
<project name="sample-build" default="run-your-swf">    
    <property file="${basedir}/your.properties.file"/>

    <target name="compile-your-app">
        <mxmlc file="${SOURCE_DIR}/ApplicationFile.mxml" compiler.debug="${IS_DEBUG}" incremental="true" failonerror="true">
            <load-config filename="${DEFAULT_FLEX_CONFIG}"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::DEBUG" value="${IS_DEBUG}"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::FLASH_AUTHORING" value="${IS_FLASH_AUTHORING}"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::IS_RELEASE" value="${IS_RELEASE}"/>
        </mxmlc>
    </target>

    <target name="rename-your-swf" depends="compile-your-app">
        <copy file="${OUTPUT_DIR}/feed/FeedComponent.swf" tofile="${OUTPUT_DIR}/YourNewSexyFilename.swf"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run-your-swf" depends="rename-your-swf">
        <exec executable="${STANDALONE_FLASH_DEBUG_PLAYER}">
            <arg line="${OUTPUT_DIR}/YourNewSexyFilename.swf"/>
        </exec>
    </target>

</project>
```

you need only define all ${VARIABLES} I've listed in "your.properties.file", like so:

```
FLASH_PLAYER_DEBUG=/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Players/Debug/Flash Player Debugger.app/Contents/MacOS/Flash Player Debugger
IS_DEBUG=true
```

(et cetera)

And anyway - what's in a name?  A program by any other name, would be as awesome... B-)